# How to show separate error messages in nuxtjs using async

Tags: php, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a public function that checks

1. if the entered email already exists or not.
2. if the entered code is matching the code of the invited school.

Now the function is showing 2 errors even when only one of them is wrong.
I am having trouble showing the errors independently. I just started digging around codes and trying to help a friend here. Don't know what I am doing.

below is the
ApplicantUserController.php on the server side

```
public function existEmailCode(UserExistEmailCodeRequest $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validationData();
        $exist = ApplicantUser::whereEmail($data['email'])->exists()
            || School::whereQrPathPassword($data['school_code'])->doesntExist();
        return new ExistResource1(['exist' => $exist]);
    }
```

below is student side index.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="login-container signup">
    <ValidationObserver ref="observer1" tag="div">
      <InputComponent
        v-if="currentPage === 1"
        :multilinguals="multilinguals"
        :lang="lang"
        :val.sync="property"
        @next="onNextPage"
      />
..........
  beforeMount() {
    const token = this.$route.query.id
    if (token === null || token === undefined) {
      // @ts-ignore
      this.$toast.show(this.multilinguals.texts['26'][this.getLang()], {
        type: 'error',
        duration: 3000
      })
      // @ts-ignore
      this.$router.push('/')
      return
    }
    if (typeof token === 'string') {
      this.property.token = token
    }

    this.unsubscribe.push(
      // @ts-ignore
      this.applicantUser.$subscribe(
        'setNetworkState',
        (payload: NetworkStatus) => {
          if (
            this.applicantUser.actionType ===
            ApplicantUserActionType.ExistEmailCode
          ) {
            if (payload === NetworkStatus.SUCCESS) {
              if (!this.applicantUser.emailCodeExist?.exist) {
                this.pageIndex = 2
                return
              }
              // @ts-ignore
              this.$refs.observer1.setErrors({
                email: this.multilinguals.texts['27'][this.getLang()],
                school_code: this.multilinguals.texts['43'][this.getLang()]
              })
            } else if (payload === NetworkStatus.ERROR) {
...............
 async onNextPage() {
    // @ts-ignore
    const validateResult = await this.$refs.observer1.validate()
    if (
      !validateResult ||
      this.applicantUser.networkState === NetworkStatus.PROGRESS
    ) {
      return
    }
    this.applicantUser.existEmailCode({
      email: this.property.email,
      school_code: this.property.school_code
    })
  }
```

input.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>
      <MultiLingual index="1" :texts="multilinguals.texts" :lang="lang" />
    </h1>
    <div class="row mb-50">
      <div class="col-md-7 bdRight col-12">
        <div class="form-group required">
          <label class="control-label">
            <MultiLingual
              index="3"
              :texts="multilinguals.texts"
              :lang="lang"
            />&nbsp;<span class="requiredTag"
              ><MultiLingual index="2" :texts="multilinguals.texts" :lang="lang"
            /></span>
          </label>
          <ValidationInput
            class-name="form-control"
            input-type="email"
            :multi-lingual="{
              index: 3,
              texts: multilinguals.texts,
              lang: lang
            }"
            element-id="email"
            rules="required|email"
            :value.sync="property.email"
            place-holder="example@example.com"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required">
          <label class="control-label">
            <MultiLingual
              index="4"
              :texts="multilinguals.texts"
              :lang="lang"
            />&nbsp;
            <span class="requiredTag">
              <MultiLingual
                index="2"
                :texts="multilinguals.texts"
                :lang="lang"
              />
            </span>
          </label>
          <ValidationInput
            class-name="form-control"
            input-type="password"
            :multi-lingual="{
              index: 4,
              texts: multilinguals.texts,
              lang: lang
            }"
            element-id="password"
            rules="required|password"
            :value.sync="property.password"
          />
          <span class="text-sm">
            <MultiLingual index="5" :texts="multilinguals.texts" :lang="lang" />
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required">
          <label class="control-label">
            <MultiLingual
              index="6"
              :texts="multilinguals.texts"
              :lang="lang"
            />&nbsp;
            <span class="requiredTag">
              <MultiLingual
                index="2"
                :texts="multilinguals.texts"
                :lang="lang"
              />
            </span>
          </label>
          <ValidationInput
            class-name="form-control"
            :value.sync="property.school_code"
            input-type="text"
            element-id="school_code"
            place-holder="9999"
            :multi-lingual="{
              index: 6,
              texts: multilinguals.texts,
              lang: lang
            }"
            max-length="4"
            rules="required|numeric|min:4"
          />
          <span class="text-sm">
            <MultiLingual index="7" :texts="multilinguals.texts" :lang="lang" />
          </span>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="termsCheckContainer">
          <ValidationProvider
            v-slot="{ errors }"
            vid="checked"
            :rules="{ required: { allowFalse: false } }"
          >
            <input v-model="property.checked" type="checkbox" :value="1" />
            <span>
              <MultiLingual
                index="8"
                :texts="multilinguals.texts"
                :lang="lang"
              />
            </span>
            <div
              v-if="errors.length"
              style="display: block"
              class="invalid-feedback"
            >
              {{ multilinguals.texts['28'][getLang()] }}
            </div>
          </ValidationProvider>
        </div>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" @click.prevent="onNext">
          <MultiLingual index="9" :texts="multilinguals.texts" :lang="lang" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 d-none">
        <p class="welcomeSideText">
          <MultiLingual index="10" :texts="multilinguals.texts" :lang="lang" />
        </p>
        <div class="sideIllust">
          <img src="~assets/images/img/img-slider-img.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="tipsContainer text-left mb-30">
      <MultiLingual index="11" :texts="multilinguals.texts" :lang="lang" />
    </div>
    <div class="haveAccount">
      <MultiLingual index="12" :texts="multilinguals.texts" :lang="lang" />
      <nuxt-link to="/signin">
        <MultiLingual index="13" :texts="multilinguals.texts" :lang="lang" />
      </nuxt-link>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, PropSync } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'
import { BaseVue } from '~/pages/base'
// @ts-ignore
import MultiLingual from '@/components/MultiLingual'
import ValidationInput from '~/components/ValidationInput.vue'
import { IApplicantUserAddRequest } from '~/repositories/request/ApplicantUserRequest'

@Component({
  components: {
    ValidationInput,
    MultiLingual
  }
})
export default class InputComponent extends BaseVue {
  @Prop()
  multilinguals!: any

  @Prop()
  lang?: string

  @PropSync('val')
  property!: IApplicantUserAddRequest

  onNext() {
    this.$emit('next')
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Solved this by checking them one by one if that makes sense.
At server side

```
public function existEmailCode(UserExistEmailCodeRequest $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validationData();
        return new ExistResource1(['emailExist'=>ApplicantUser::whereEmail($data['email'])->exists(),
            'schoolCodeExist'=>School::whereQrPathPassword($data['school_code'])->doesntExist()]);
    }
```

At client side.

```
    this.unsubscribe.push(
      // @ts-ignore
      this.applicantUser.$subscribe(
        'setNetworkState',
        (payload: NetworkStatus) => {
          if (
            this.applicantUser.actionType ===
            ApplicantUserActionType.ExistEmailCode
          ) {
            if (payload === NetworkStatus.SUCCESS) {
              if (
                !this.applicantUser.emailCodeExist?.emailExist &&
                !this.applicantUser.emailCodeExist?.schoolCodeExist
              ) {
                this.pageIndex = 2
                return
              }
              // @ts-ignore
              this.$refs.observer1.setErrors({
                email: [],
                school_code: []
              })
              if (this.applicantUser.emailCodeExist?.emailExist) {
                // @ts-ignore
                this.$refs.observer1.setErrors({
                  email: this.multilinguals.texts['27'][this.getLang()]
                })
              }
              if (this.applicantUser.emailCodeExist?.schoolCodeExist) {
                // @ts-ignore
                this.$refs.observer1.setErrors({
                  school_code: this.multilinguals.texts['43'][this.getLang()]
                })
              }
            } else if (payload === NetworkStatus.ERROR) {
              // @ts-ignore
              this.$toast.show(
                this.multilinguals.common['25'][this.getLang()],
                {
                  type: 'error',
                  duration: 3000
                }
              )
            }
          } else if (
            this.applicantUser.actionType === ApplicantUserActionType.Add
          ) {
            if (payload === NetworkStatus.SUCCESS) {
              this.$router.push('/dashboard')
            } else if (payload === NetworkStatus.ERROR) {
              // @ts-ignore
              this.$toast.show(
                this.multilinguals.common['25'][this.getLang()],
                {
                  type: 'error',
                  duration: 3000
                }
              )
            }
          }
        }
      )
    )
  }

  async onNextPage() {
    // @ts-ignore
    const validateResult = await this.$refs.observer1.validate()
    if (
      !validateResult ||
      this.applicantUser.networkState === NetworkStatus.PROGRESS
    ) {
      return
    }
    this.applicantUser.existEmailCode({
      email: this.property.email,
      school_code: this.property.school_code
    })
  }
```

User.ts

```
  // @ts-ignore
  @action
  // eslint-disable-next-line camelcase
  async existEmailCode(payload: IApplicantUserEmailCodeExistRequest) {
    this.setActionType(ApplicantUserActionType.ExistEmailCode)
    this.setNetworkState(NetworkStatus.PROGRESS)
    try {
      const response = await ApplicantUserRepository.existEmailCode(payload)
      this.setExistEmailCode(response.data)
      this.setNetworkState(NetworkStatus.SUCCESS)
      return response
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
      this.setError(e)
      this.setNetworkState(getErrorStatus(e))
    }
  }
```

on userrequest.ts

```
export interface IApplicantUserEmailCodeExistRequest {
  email: string
  school_code: string
}
```