# VeeValidate 3 server side validation error showing even when the field is correct

Tags: jquery, typescript, vue.js, validation, vee-validate

I have a function that checks 2 things

```
    {
        $data = $request->validationData();
        $exist = ApplicantUser::whereEmail($data['email'])->exists()
            || School::whereQrPathPassword($data['school_code'])->doesntExist();
        return new ExistResource1(['exist' => $exist]);
    }
```

and 2 messages for each field

```
this.$refs.observer1.setErrors({
                email: this.multilinguals.texts['27'][this.getLang()],
                school_code: this.multilinguals.texts['43'][this.getLang()]
              })
```

but when only 1 of them is wrong both of the field shows error.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the or(**||**) condition you are using. You should use and(**&&**) to confirm the validation to run only when both of your conditions are met

Comment: Thanks for the reply! When i use && instead of || when only one of the condition is met it goes through. I need it to both be correct to continue.

Comment: For example If i use && when only one field is correct it goes through without showing any errors. The validator works correctly. The problem is because the function is checking 2 fields simultaneously when one of them fails both error messages are displayed. I just want the error to display when the field actually has error.

Comment: I solved it somehow. It took eternity. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63152104/how-to-show-separate-error-messages-in-nuxtjs-using-async